# how to shift elements of array from one column to another column by using pointer in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

how to shift elements of array from one column to another column by using pointer to pointer in c++
When I do this, it says "Reference to non-static member function must be called"

```
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        array[n]->my_data[i] = array[n]->my_arr[i+1];
    }
```

Comment: What are `array` and `my_data` declared as? This code goes out of bounds of `my_arr`.

Comment: Can you show the code on how you've declared this array's structure?

Comment: `array[n]->my_data[i] = array[n]->my_arr[i+1];` seems like a typo. Did you mean `array[n]->my_data[i] = array[n]->my_data[i+1];`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau It might, but we don't know because we don't know what size or my_arr or anything is.

Comment: Hello, hello. Where'd you go?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of C++ ways to do it. The second one, using `std::rotate`, is to be preferred.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void show(const std::vector<int> & vec) {
    for (auto v : vec) {
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };

    // Re-invent wheel
    for (auto it = vec.begin() + 1; it != vec.end(); ++it) {
        *(it - 1) = std::move(*it);
    }
    vec.pop_back();
    show(vec);

    // No wheel re-invention
    std::rotate(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + 1, vec.end());
    vec.pop_back();
    show(vec);
}
```

If you want to use a fixed size array on the stack, this is the way. Do not use 
`array int[10];`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

const int sz = 5;
void show(const std::array<std::string, sz> & vec) {
    for (auto v : vec) {
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
int main() {
    std::array<std::string, sz> vec{ "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four" };

    // Roll your own
    for (auto it = vec.begin() + 1; it != vec.end(); ++it) {
        std::swap(*(it - 1), *it);
    }
    show(vec);

    // No wheel re-invention
    std::rotate(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + 1, vec.end());

    show(vec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should go without saying that the C++ way is not to use fixed arrays at all. You should prefer STL vector over fixed arrays whenever possible. That being said, this might have been an introductory assignment where you must re-invent the wheel so to speak. I’m assuming you are constrained to fixed arrays for whatever reason. If not, get rid of them!

You didn't specify what `array[n]` is or what what the size of `my_data` is, or what even `my_data` holds. I'm going to answer this assuming that `my_data` contains a bunch of integers and that you wanted to rotate every element in that array to the left by 1 "column", making the first element the new last. Here's how you could do it. You need to take care to not overrun your array length.

```
const size_t len{10};
int my_data[len] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int i, temp;
temp = my_data[0]; ///< temp copy of data at 0
for (i = 0; i != len-1; i++)
{
    my_data[i] = my_data[i+1]; ///< shift left by 1
}
my_data[i] = temp; ///< old data at 0 goes to the new end
```

> ```
> Input:
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> Output:
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
> ```